# Span as input with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, search, input, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In a webpage Im building I started to use <span>-tags as inputs with content editible flag enabled. The reason for this is that they look more nice to align up and they are able to rezise their own with when you are typing in them. And I save down the content of the span in a hidden inputfield on keyup.

I dynamicly add more spans when they are needed.

Now I need to be able to autocomplete when people are typing in my span fields, but .autocomplete seems to not work on span fields(?), is there some simple solution to this?

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="generated_name[1]" />
  <span contenteditable="true" class="editbox"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="generated_name[2]" />
  <span contenteditable="true" class="editbox"></span>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.editbox').live('keyup', function() {
      $(this).prev().val($(this).html());
    });
  });
</script>
```

That code works well for me atleast, I can add more input fields(input+span) and it works.

Now I want to be able to search while typing in the spans instead of the inputfield, and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tags = [
    "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3", "Tag4", "Tag5", "Tag6", "Tag7"
  ];
  $('.editbox').autocomplete({
    source: tags
  });
});
```

Do anyone know if this is possible in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to fix this, because autocomplete relies on being used on inputs. Then, what are those two `</value>`doing there? They should be `</span>`.
To abuse a span as an input makes no sense to me. Input is there for exactly the purpose you're using it for, and you can style an input too, this is not a good excuse for replacing them with spans.

Comment: My sulotion has been to make my own autocomplete based on the autocomplete from jqueryui, and replaced all usage of .val() with .html(). And renamed it to spanautocomplete in my local system.
_(And the </value> was a misstake)_

Comment: @Etu: Are there no issues with events (like the change event)?

Comment: Not what I notice, the biggest problem is that spans uses .html for the content, and inputs uses .val